# Linq with "where in" clause on collections

Tags: linq

I have 2 lists [Collections ]

Example:

- ListA is having 100 string keys
- ListB is having 50 string Keys

Now i want to write one linq query on ListA where i want to find common keys which are in ListB

Please help

Comment: `l1.Intersect(l2)`. Plenty of questions on SO already. Do a search.

Answer (score 2):

Take this for example:

```
//Define 2 Lists
var ListA = new List<string>();
var ListB = new List<string>();

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    //if counter smaller 50 add to both lists
    if(i < 50)
    {
        ListA.Add("Value"+i);
        ListB.Add("Value"+i);
    }
    //add only to listA 
    else
        ListA.Add("Value"+i);
}
//ListA ranges from 0 to 99
//ListB ranges from 0 to 49
var result = ListA.Intersect(ListB);
```

The output of result will be an `IEnumerable<string>` with values ranging from Value0 to Value49 since those are the keys which are in both Lists.